# NETJson, how to serialize custom type inside a collection of custom types

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, nested

How should I write this portion of code to serialize all descendant custom types?

The question regards NETJson ( https://github.com/rpgmaker/NetJSON ).

Below the code used to test it.

NETJson Serializer implementation:

```
class NETJsonFormatter
{
    static bool Initialize()
    {
        NetJSON.NetJSON.IncludeFields = true;
        NetJSON.NetJSON.IncludeTypeInformation = true;
        return true;
    }

    static bool Initialized = Initialize();

    /// <summary>
    /// Serializza un oggetto in un array di byte.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
    static public byte[] Serialize(object obj)
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(NetJSON.NetJSON.Serialize(obj));
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Trasforma un array di byte nell'oggetto originario.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
    static public object Deserialize(byte[] obj)
    {
        return NetJSON.NetJSON.Deserialize<object>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(obj));
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializza un array di byte nel Type desiderato.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static public T Deserialize<T>(byte[] obj)
    {
        return NetJSON.NetJSON.Deserialize<T>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(obj));
    }
}
```

The first object to serialize:

```
[Serializable]
public class ComplexType
{
    public ComplexType()
    {
         this.Numero = 100;
         this.Stringa = "Contenuto";
    }
    public int Numero { get; set; }
    public string Stringa { get; set; }
}
```

The second object to serialize:

```
[Serializable]
public class Message_v2 : IMessage
{
    public Message_v2()
    {
        this.Options = new List<string>();
        this.Arguments = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public bool IsEmpty { get; set; }

    public MessageCommand Command { get; set; }

    public List<string> Options { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gli Arguments del parser sono sempre KeyValue. Qual'ora mancasse il Value viene inserito null.
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<string, object> Arguments { get; set; }

    /*
     * Public methods
     */

    public void AddOptions(params string[] options)
    {
        foreach (string option in options)
            this.Options.Add(option);
    }

    public void AddArgument(string key, object value)
    {
        this.Arguments.Add(key, value);
    }

    public byte[] ToArray()
    {
        return NETJsonFormatter.Serialize(this);
    }

    public string ToXML()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// For debugging purposes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string ToJSON()
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(NETJsonFormatter.Serialize(this));
    }

    /*
     * Conversions
     */

    public static explicit operator Message_v2(byte[] source)
    {
        try
        {
            return NETJsonFormatter.Deserialize<Message_v2>(source);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And the unit test which fails.
The first test, the one on ComplexObject, passes.
To ensure the data are consistent I use DeepEqual ( https://github.com/jamesfoster/DeepEqual - 'DeepEqual' on NUGet), which provides the method .ShouldDeepEqual used for object comparison.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CreateAndRetrieveMessage()
{
    ComplexType complexArgument = new ComplexType();

        byte[] serializedComplexArgument = NETJsonFormatter.Serialize(complexArgument);
        ComplexType deserializedComplexArgument = NETJsonFormatter.Deserialize<ComplexType>(serializedComplexArgument);

        deserializedComplexArgument.ShouldDeepEqual(complexArgument);

        /* ------------------------ */

        IMessage message = ProtocolHelper.CreateMessage();
        message.Command = MessageCommand.Set;
        message.AddOptions("keys");
        message.AddArgument("Key1", "Contenuto");
        message.AddArgument("Key2", 100);
        message.AddArgument("Key3", complexArgument);

        // Send over the wire.
        byte[] serialized = message.ToArray();

        // Get the Message sent.
        var deserialized = ProtocolHelper.CreateMessage(serialized);

        deserialized.ShouldDeepEqual(message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

from the [wiki](https://github.com/rpgmaker/NetJSON/wiki/Quick-Guide)

> Dictionary
>       - Value(Object) supported Dictionary, IList, Primitive Types, and Enums

I think this is your problem, just try to serialize an object dicitionnary, it will fail, but a complexType dictionnary succeed...

```
ComplexType complexArgument = new ComplexType();

byte[] serializedComplexArgument = NETJsonFormatter.Serialize(complexArgument);
ComplexType deserializedComplexArgument = NETJsonFormatter.Deserialize<ComplexType>(serializedComplexArgument);

deserializedComplexArgument.ShouldDeepEqual(complexArgument);


/* ------------------------ */

var complexTypeDictionnary = new Dictionary<string, ComplexType>();
complexTypeDictionnary.Add("Key3", complexArgument);

byte[] serializedDic2 = NETJsonFormatter.Serialize(complexTypeDictionnary);
var deserializeDictionnary2 = NETJsonFormatter.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, ComplexType>>(serializedDic2);

deserializeDictionnary2.ShouldDeepEqual(complexTypeDictionnary); // works


/* ------------------------ */

var objectDictionnary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
objectDictionnary.Add("Key1", "Contenuto");
objectDictionnary.Add("Key2", 100);
objectDictionnary.Add("Key3", complexArgument);

byte[] serializedDic = NETJsonFormatter.Serialize(objectDictionnary);
var deserializeDictionnary = NETJsonFormatter.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(serializedDic);

deserializeDictionnary.ShouldDeepEqual(objectDictionnary); // doesn't work
```

**Edit**

I used to play with NewtonSoft for Json serialization, maybe your searching for performance improvement or other but it works well with it ;)

```
/* ------------------------ */

var objectDictionnary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
objectDictionnary.Add("Key1", "Contenuto");
objectDictionnary.Add("Key2", 100);
objectDictionnary.Add("Key3", complexArgument);


byte[] serializedDicNewton = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject( objectDictionnary));
var deserializeDictionnaryNewton = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(serializedDicNewton));

deserializeDictionnaryNewton.ShouldDeepEqual(objectDictionnary); // works too
```

Comment: This sounds good. But my problem is my Message_v2.Arguments are dynamic and I've no idea or control on which type users choose to input them.
So I can't change the declaration of Message_v2.Arguments from Dictionary<string, object> to Dictionary<string, ComplexType>.

In fact, in my unit test I wrote explicitly three values, one int, one string, one ComplexType.

Comment: Maybe use an other serializer, newtonsoft one works well for this use case, i edited my post

Comment: Improvement on performance was the key of using NETJson.

Actually I'm using BinaryFormatter to do the serialization and send over the wire and works well. I've "played" with NewtonSoft for Json serialization with no issues at all.
So, you're right, if I'd like to serialize on Json I'd use more 'robust' json serializer but I opened the question using tag "NETJson" and stackoverflow.com did respond "You cannot start a question using the tag NETJson if you don't have 1500 reputation points".

Eh. :(

Comment: Does your objects type in your dictionnary a really dynamic or is it a known subset of type ? If you know the different type to use you could implement an other logic to dispatch known type in an internal dictionary with the good type so the serialization could work with NETJson.

Comment: The values on Dictionary (referencing to Message_v2.Arguments) are not in a subset of known types.
To be more specific so you'd figure out what types will be used... I use this class for communication over TCP in a cache client-server project I wrote, and actually I'm using BinaryFormatter to do serialization.
All works fine.

The Type(s) contained in the Dictionary are not known at runtime.
The communication class serialize over bytes and send to server, which store it and send it back to client over bytes.

i.e.: Dictionary<string, byte[]> wont' work either. At least not with NETJson.

Answer (score 0):

NETJson doesn't properly serialize a Dictionary cause Object it's the base Type but it can serialize a lot of primitives (included byte array) so I found a solution (well, a workaround for now cause my eyes bleed looking at code - but it works great).

Class Helper for NETJson

```
class NETJsonFormatter
{
    public NETJsonFormatter() { }

    static bool Initialize()
    {
        NetJSON.NetJSON.IncludeFields = true;
        NetJSON.NetJSON.IncludeTypeInformation = true;
        return true;
    }

    static bool Initialized = Initialize();

    /// <summary>
    /// Serializza un oggetto in un array di byte.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    //[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
    static public byte[] SerializeWithType(object obj)
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(NetJSON.NetJSON.Serialize(obj.GetType(), obj));

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Trasforma un array di byte nell'oggetto originario.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    //[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
    static public object DeserializeWithType(Type type, byte[] obj)
    {
        return NetJSON.NetJSON.Deserialize(type, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(obj));
    }

    static public byte[] Serialize<T>(T obj)
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(NetJSON.NetJSON.Serialize(obj));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializza un array di byte nel Type desiderato.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static public T Deserialize<T>(byte[] obj)
    {
        return NetJSON.NetJSON.Deserialize<T>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(obj));
    }

}
```

Second object to serialize (which didn't succeed on already unit test)

```
[Serializable]
public class Message_v2 //: IMessage
{
    public Message_v2()
    {
        this.Options = new List<string>();
        this.Arguments = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        this.ValuesForNETJson = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();
        this.TypesForNETJson = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
    }

    public bool IsEmpty { get; set; }

    public MessageCommand Command { get; set; }

    public List<string> Options { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gli Arguments del parser sono sempre KeyValue. Qual'ora mancasse il Value viene inserito null.
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<string, object> Arguments { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serializzo gli Arguments in byte array.  
    /// string - Key di Arguments[n]
    /// byte[] - contenuto serializzato di Arguments[n]
    /// </summary>
    public IDictionary<string, byte[]> ValuesForNETJson { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, Type> TypesForNETJson { get; set; }

    /*
     * Public methods
     */

    public void AddOptions(params string[] options)
    {
        foreach (string option in options)
            this.Options.Add(option);
    }

    public void AddArgument(string key, object value)
    {
        this.Arguments.Add(key, value);
        this.ValuesForNETJson.Add(key, NETJsonFormatter.SerializeWithType(value));
        this.TypesForNETJson.Add(key, value.GetType());
    }

    public byte[] ToArray()
    {
        //this.Arguments.ToDictionary(x => x.Value == null);
        return NETJsonFormatter.Serialize(this);
    }

    /*
     * Conversions
     */

    public static explicit operator Message_v2(byte[] source)
    {
        try
        {
            Message_v2 message = NETJsonFormatter.Deserialize<Message_v2>(source);
            int count = message.ValuesForNETJson.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                string key = message.Arguments.ElementAt(i).Key;
                Type type = message.TypesForNETJson.ElementAt(i).Value;
                byte[] value = message.ValuesForNETJson[key];
                message.Arguments[key] = NETJsonFormatter.DeserializeWithType(type, value);
            }
            return message;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

For sure my solution will be reworked cause it's not optimal, far from that.
Adding two Dictionary to the class make it grow and be larger than same class serialized using ProtoBuf, and make it slower.